# Linux Makefile project debugging best practices and tools

Tags: linux, debugging, gcc, makefile

I'm comming from Windows background and are diving a little into Linux programming. I'm interested, what are the best practices in debugging a classical Makefile project (breakpoints, stepping, call stack, ...) in Linux using GCC ?

Best regards !

Comment: Sorry, but voting to close : "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.". Please read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs. Tnx

Comment: I don't think this question is asking about tools or other off-site resources.  The ask is "what are the best practices [for] debugging a classical Makefile project?".  The problem here is that the question is primarily a matter of opinion; what I consider a great idea you might consider lunacy.

Comment: Having said that: learn to use `gdb` and `printf()`.

Comment: There is no `classical Makefile project`, a Makefile is just a description of how to build a project.

Comment: I don't really see how would a Makefile influence the debugging, except maybe that you can have a Makefile variable deciding whether you will have debugging symbols, optimizations, etc. or not.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by debugging a makefile project with gcc.  However, if you have a GNU makefile which is causing you problems, then I can HIGHLY recommend the following:

1. start with `make --debug`, it will tell you lots about which rule is being executed and which target patterns were being matched against etc.
2. install [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/).  it's absolutely the best thing sinced sliced makefiles. Start with its debug output `remake -x`. If you're still confused, use the interactive mode `remake -X`.  In the interactive console, type `h` for help, `t` to get info on the current target and `s` to single step. There's a whole bunch of other commands too but this should get you started.  You can also breakpoint on make targets etc.  Seriously, remake ftw.

Comment: Recently added to remake  4.xxx+dbg-1.4 was the `--post-mortem` option. It enters the debugger just before it would otherwise just die with an error or fatal error. Not sure why I didn't think of it earlier.